# How does quality help damage reduction?

Tags: wurm-online

I've been trying to figure out how quality helps damage reduction. For example is an 8 quality plate helm better then a 30 quality chain helm? Or even better, what's a good ratio for determining when quality is better then a type of armor?

Comment: I think it's hard to really compare armour types without access to the formulas behind them, which only Rolf knows afaik. You should choose one type of armour over another based on other characteristics like weight, movement penalty, attack penalty